# validate textbox while typing php

Tags: php, html, validation

I am having a form with a text input field. The text input need to be validated simultaneously when the user enters the data.

```
<form method="post" action="Newsletter/tester.php">
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email  *" maxlength="50" required>
    <input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

The input `email` textbox should be validated on the server side, but I don't have any idea about validating the text field while typing.

Is there any way to do it using php script?

Comment: Use Javascript (or jQuery) with an Ajax call to the server that'll check for the validity on `keyup` on the `input` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use jQuery and PHP, here's an exemple of what you can do:

**HTML**

```
<form action="Newsletter/tester.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email-input">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <br/>
    <span id="email-validate">Waiting for user input...</span>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // When the user types something in the input
    $('#email-input').on('keyup', function(e) {

        // set the variables
        var $input = $(this)
        ,   value  = $input.val()
        ,   data   = {
                email: value   
        };

        // perform an ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'my/validator.php', // this is the target
            method: 'get', // method
            data: data, // pass the input value to server
            success: function(r) { // if the http response code is 200
                $('#email-validate').css('color', 'green').html(r);
                $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            error: function(r) { // if the http response code is other than 200
                $('#email-validate').css('color', 'red').html(r);
                $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }

        });
    });

});
```

**PHP** (>= 5.4)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo 'The email '.$email.' is valid';
    } else {
        http_response_code(412);
        echo 'The email '.$email.' is not valid';
    }
}
```

Comment: There would be a performance issue & dangling responses, so `abort` the previous ajax calls of email validations before sending new

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved in PHP and Javascript. As you type, a Javascript sends the written data through an Ajax call to php, wich returns it ...

The right way is to validate the code

1. In javascript, as it is beeing typed. This is done with an event `onkeydown="validate_email(this)"` in the `input`
2. Make sure the email address is valid before submitting the form by adding a `onsubmit="return email_valid();"`. If the javascript function email_valid returns true, the form is submitted otherwise it is not submitted.
3. In PHP as the complete data is being sent, confirm it really is a correct email address in `$_REQUEST['email']`